# How to view the Ansible When Conditional Evaluation

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to use Ansible to upgrade a Cisco Router, and using the cli_config module to check that the boot marker is set correctly prior to me actually rebooting.

I'm trying to use the when clause to prevent the playbook from applying changes unless the configuration looks correct

I want to make sure that the variable "filename" - which is the name of the image passed by the admin to the playbook - is contained within the output to a command which checks the boot file - which is registered to a variable called "boot_sys_marker_running_config"

I have already tried:

`when: filename in boot_sys_marker_running_config.stdout`

I have also tried

`when: filename == "boot_sys_marker_running_config.stdout"`

I've tried debugging these with the -vvvv option when running the playbooks and the `debugger: always` set inside the playbook but no insight

I seem to always get that the conditional was not successful - but I can't see what the conditional thinks I want it to evaluate - does anyone know how to "look into" the conditional so I can modify it appropriately?

option for playbook:

`-e "filename=csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA.bin"`

part of playbook where I register variable and try to use conditional

```
- name: check to see that the correct boot system marker has been configured   
  cli_command:
    command: "show run | i boot system"   
  register: boot_sys_marker_running_config   ignore_errors: yes
- name: copy running config to startup when boot marker is correct   
  cli_command:
    command: "copy running-config startup-config"   
  register: writing_config_to_startup
  ignore_errors: yes
  when: filename in boot_sys_marker_running_config.stdout
```

I have a debug task to show contents of boot_sys_marker_running_config:

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [r3-cvpn1.corp.ncsc.gov.uk] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "stdout": "boot system bootflash:csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA/packages.conf",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "boot system bootflash:csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA/packages.conf"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the playbook, outputs or the value of variables?

Comment: first task output also pls.

Comment: it only really shows "ok" - so have pasted debug output

Comment: Can you check if it is the problem with alignment for when condition. when should be under name.

Comment: sorry - indentation got out of line when pasting - have corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the pending `.bin` from the *filename*. This extension is missing in the string `stdout`

```
-e "filename=csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA.bin"
```

Correct

```
-e "filename=csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA"
```

The correct condition should be

```
when: boot_sys_marker_running_config.stdout is search(filename)
```

The test below works as expected.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    filename: 'csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA'
    stdout: 'boot system bootflash:csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA/packages.conf'
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: filename found
      when: stdout is search(filename)
```

Comment: thankyou! This also helped me find this page, very useful for other tasks I'm doing: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that your example filename `csr1000v-universalk9azn.16.11.01b.SPA.bin` is not anywhere in your output.

That being said, when you use a conditional of the form:

```
a_string in a_list
```

you are checking if `a_list` contains an element that is **exactly** `a_string`.

This should not be confused with

```
a_substring in a_string
```

where you check if `a_substring` matches a portion of `a_string`.

This could work using `stdout_lines` in your example but you would have to make that check for every element in the list.

The easiest way in your situation is to use `stdout` directly where all lines are alreacy concatenated in one single string:

```
when: filename in stdout
```

You still have to fix your filename thought and remove the `.bin` extension for this to work with your simple data.